# Lead on Financial Service Cloud

Tags: lead-conversion, person-accounts, financial-services-cloud

Is there a way we can remove the existing lead record types and create a custom record type but will populate on the referral summary in the Accounts?

Our Scenarios-

1. A lead is an individual person who becomes a person account and an opportunity(optional)
2. A lead can be the company who during the conversion process is created as a Business Account & a Contact, Opportunity (optional)

**Aim**

We wanted one record type where it serves both the lead as an individual and lead as a company with the contact attached.

**Pains**

We tried deactivating the person referral record type but the issue we get is when using the business referral record type upon conversion it will not create a person account, we receive an error where an individual account needs to be selected. Similarly if we deactivate the business referral record type it breaks the component under an existing account who referred the lead (Referrals made summary- Financial Service)

**Summary**

I have had a look at the documentation and have gone through the custom metadata types but to no avail. Any help on this would be extremely valuable